# Sorting a paged WPF ListView will sort only the items on current page

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, sorting

I have a listView with pages, and I try to sort it on column header click, but the problem is that it will sort only the items on the current page.I want the sorter to sort all the items and to display the items on pages in the right order. Example: now if I have 5,3,1 on page 1 and 2,6,4 on page 2 it will show 1,3,5 on page 1 and 2,4,6 on page2, and it needs to be 1,2,3 on page1 and 4,5,6 on page 2.

How I do it? This is the code I use:

```
CollectionViewSource view = new CollectionViewSource();
ObservableCollection<Server> Source = new ObservableCollection<Server>();
int currentPageIndex = 0;
int itemPerPage = 13;
int totalPage = 0;
//populating the listview
public void refreshList()
{
    int itemcount = 0;
    foreach (string id in server_id)
    {
        if (id != null && id != "")
        {
            Source.Add(new Server
            {
                ID = Int32.Parse(id),
                NAME = server_name[Int32.Parse(id)],
                PING = 0
            }); 
            itemcount++;
        }
    }

    totalPage = itemcount / itemPerPage;
    if (itemcount % itemPerPage != 0)
    {
        totalPage += 1;
    }
    view.Source = Source;
    view.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(view_Filter);
    listView1.DataContext = view;
} 



//Paging
private void ShowCurrentPageIndex()
{
    this.next.Content = (currentPageIndex + 1).ToString();
}
void view_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Source.IndexOf((Server)e.Item);

    if (index >= itemPerPage * currentPageIndex && index < itemPerPage * (currentPageIndex     + 1))
    {
        e.Accepted = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Accepted = false;
    }
}
private void btnPrev_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
// Display previous page
    if (currentPageIndex > 0)
    {
        currentPageIndex--;
        view.View.Refresh();
    }
    ShowCurrentPageIndex();

}

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
// Display next page
    if (currentPageIndex < totalPage - 1)
    {
        currentPageIndex++;
        view.View.Refresh();
    }
    ShowCurrentPageIndex();
}
//Sorting
GridViewColumnHeader _lastHeaderClicked = null;
ListSortDirection _lastDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;

void GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewColumnHeader headerClicked = e.OriginalSource as GridViewColumnHeader;
    ListSortDirection direction;

    if (headerClicked != null)
    {
        if (headerClicked != _lastHeaderClicked)
        {
            direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        }
        else
        {
            if (_lastDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
            }
            else
            {
                direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            }
        }
        string header = headerClicked.Column.Header as string;
        Sort(header, direction);
        _lastHeaderClicked = headerClicked;
        _lastDirection = direction;
    }

}

private void Sort(string sortBy, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        var sortProperty = typeof(Server).GetProperty(sortBy);
        if (direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            Source = new ObservableCollection<Server>(Source.OrderBy(s => sortProperty.GetValue(s)));
        }
        else
        {
            Source = new ObservableCollection<Server>(Source.OrderByDescending(s => sortProperty.GetValue(s)));
        }

        view.Source = Source;
        view.View.Refresh();
    }
```

ListView XAML:

```
    <ListView Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LVitem}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="502" Margin="10,130,10,0" FontSize="20"  GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler" FontFamily="/WpfApplication2;component/Resources/#Purista SemiBold" Background="#66181F2C" BorderThickness="1.000001"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeader}"  >
                    <GridViewColumn Header=" ID" Width="0" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header=" NAME" Width="500"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NAME}"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Header=" PING" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PING}"  />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button x:Name="next" Content="Next" Margin="1179,0,0,0" Click="btnNext_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="prev" Content="Prev" Margin="1179,0,0,0" Click="btnPrev_Click"/>
```

and this is the style used for listview:

```
 <Style x:Key="LVitem" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#663F5768" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#992E4051" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="7"/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="UpperHighlight" Fill="#FFE3F7FF" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                    <GridViewRowPresenter  x:Name="Content" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0,0,0,1"  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#66597B93" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#99364B5F" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDADADA" Offset="1"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I need to see the XAML for your listView1

Comment: Added to the post. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way you are filtering the items you have to sort your Source collection instead of the items.

```
private void Sort(string sortBy, ListSortDirection direction)
{
    var sortProperty = typeof(Server).GetProperty(sortBy);
    if(sortProperty == null) return;
    if (direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        Source = new ObservableCollection<Server>(Source.OrderBy(s => sortProperty.GetValue(s, null)));
    }
    else
    {
        Source = new ObservableCollection<Server>(Source.OrderByDescending(s => sortProperty.GetValue(s, null)));
    }

    view.Source = Source;
    view.View.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer. I think the view needs to be refreshed rather than listView1.

Comment: I added `view.View.Refresh()` and its still the same.

Comment: I tried the code in the last edit and it says `No overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 arguments` and it needs to be `GetValue(object obj,object[] index)`.What i use as index?

Comment: Sorry, I'm already using C# 4.5 in wich you don't need to specify the index. The index is for indexed properties, so don't need bother about that. In your Server class you don't have indexed properties. I updated my answer.

Comment: Now i have another problem : `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WpfApplication2.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` is thrown at GetValue(s,null)

Comment: Set a brakepoint at the first line and tell me if the value of sortBy is a name of any property on the Server class.

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault, I accidentaly renamed one header name.Now it works but the numbers in ID column are not sorted correctly. They are sorted like 1 10 11 12 2 3... instead of 1 2 3 ... 10 11 12.

Comment: Is the ID property of type 'int'? Make sure the list is not sorted by the view.

Comment: Yes, the type of ID is int.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code. The integers are sorted correctly. If you set a breakpoint after the sort you'll see that the Source collection is sorted ok. Remove all the previous code that was sorting using the view using the SortDescriptors. Also note that when you sort by NAME you'll have the string sorting, so if you have numbers as names they will be sorted like 1 10 11 2 3